# Are brush pass-throughs safe on junction boxes with 120V power?

Tags: electrical

I'd like to know if it's safe to put a brush pass-through on a junction box that has 120V power.  Seems to me that someone could push some fingers through and touch the 120V connection inside by accident.

Here's an [example brush pass-through](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-White-1-Gang-Audio-Video-Wall-Plate-1-Pack-41075-DBW/301638005?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&srsltid=AR5OiO1hglJQ0SRnYyhMryWj7Dx8sUpcWjRRHyDZvbpE8eqzzu10g6oXTqI).

Picture of them side by side below.

[image]

Comment: Not only use box divider (or entire separate boxes for low voltage and line voltage) but also skip the brush and put in keystone jacks for ethernet, rather than stringing patch cables through the wall, which is implied by what is written about the brush pass-through on your diagram.

Answer (score 16):

No, you can not do this. They do make box dividers and boxes that are already divided. You would need to use one of those here.

[image]
[src](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-2-Gang-Blue-Non-Metallic-Dual-Voltage-Box-Bracket-SC200DVR/100146034)

Comment: Box dividers make a lot of sense.  Thanks!  I will make sure that those get used.

Comment: It's worth clarifying: it is a code violation to mix low-voltage and line-voltage wiring in the same box, period - not just if you use the "brush pass-through". You need the divider just as much if you're using jacks on a faceplate.